# How to reorder a playlist?

Tags: python, dailymotion-api

How can I reorder a playlist using the Dailymotion API (via Python)?

I've looked through the [api](https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/#/playlist) and found no mention of a video's order within the playlist. My playlists were imported in reverse order and I'm trying to avoid having to reorder 150+ episodes x 100 playlists.

I have this [working](https://github.com/cgranier/pytube) using the YouTube API already...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder your playlist by POSTing the new order of your video IDs with this endpoint: 
https://api.dailymotion.com/playlist/{PLAYLIST_ID}/videos?ids={VIDEO_ID},...,{VIDEO_ID}

With our SDK python the method would be like this

```
d.post('/playlist/{PLAYLIST_ID}/videos', {'ids' : '{VIDEO_ID},...,{VIDEO_ID}'})
```

You can list your current playlist order with this endpoint:
https://api.dailymotion.com/playlist/{playlist_id}/videos?fields=id

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to remove the videos from the playlist first? (Will this create duplicates?)

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of videos I can pass this way? Can I reorder 150 videos, for instance?

Comment: You don't need to remove your videos. You can see this call as a definition of the content of your playlist so it will rewrite all its content. You can reorder up to 150 videos this way

Comment: Thanks. What if the playlist is longer than 150 videos? Since there's no "position" indicator (other than the order in the API call), how would I order more than 150 videos?